# NPM install maven build failure

Tags: angular, maven, npm, build, processor

I am trying to build an Angular JS project using 'mvn clean install' command. The 'npm install' execution specified in pom.xml is as follows:

```
<execution>
<id>npm install</id>
<goals>
<goal>npm</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<arguments>install</arguments>
</configuration>
</execution>
```

However, this execution fails with the following error:
Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.4:npm (npm install) on project : Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073741819 (Exit value: -1073741819) -> [Help 1]

I tried with different versions of the frontend maven plugin but to no avail. Strangely, I was able to build the same project successfully in another laptop with the same settings. On comparing the two laptops, only difference I could make out is the processor. Though both laptops use Intel I7, the one in which the build fails is the latest 11th gen processor and the other is a 10th gen processor. Although it isn't quite different, could this be a possibility. Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
<configuration>
    <nodeVersion>v12.12.0</nodeVersion>
    <npmVersion>6.14.4</npmVersion>
</configuration>
```

and was able to fix the issue by deleting the node_modules folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Though the npm install works fine with certain later versions, the consecutive executions (bower and gulp) fail. Additionally, the recommended version of node is 4.2.6 for our source code and hence we need to use this only for the build. Please let me know if there is any other reason for this version not to work in the build.